# how to polynomially check if a given boolean formula is unsatisfiable

Tags: satisfiability, p-vs-np

Since SAT is np-complete, there is a polynomial algorithm to check if a given solution for any particular formula is correct. Just substitute the values and solve. But what if one claims that the given formula is unsatisfiable, is there a polynomial way to check if the claim is true... Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NP only requires you to have a polynomial size proof for "yes" instances.

co-NP is the class of problems that requires polynomial size proofs for "no" instances.

SAT is in NP, but is not known to be in co-NP. Whether NP = co-NP is an open problem (and proving that SAT is in co-NP would resolve this problem in the affirmative).

So to answer the question in your title, how to polynomially check if a given boolean formula is unsatisfiable: no one knows whether that could be done in general.

Comment: " no one knows whether that could be done in general. " you mean in polynomial time right ?

Comment: Also,  " NP only requires you to have a polynomial size proof for "yes" instances. " , i think that's exactly what i was looking for, can you give some link to any website or maybe any book where it mentions, I want some sort of formal proof, cuz i looked the definition for np problems, and no website i checked states in this form - NP only requires you to have a polynomial size proof for "yes" instances.......                       so i desperately want some sort of authentic source where it mentions it in  this way, if you don't mind

Comment: @AlexMatyasaur Yes, in polynomial time + size for the certificate. Regarding an authoritative source, any book on complexity should have this in the definition of NP. You could also read the formal definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Formal_definition) precisely: note how the requirements are different for the "yes" instances ("For all x in L") and for the "no" instances ("For all x not in L"). For the "no" instances it only requires that it doesn't give *false positive* proofs, not that it proves the instance is in fact a "no" instance.

Comment: Also, "I want some sort of formal proof" - this is not possible. This is part of the *definition* of NP, not some proven property.

Comment: by formal proof i meant some source obviously; thanks for the wikipedia subsection link... i was confused if definition of np includes polynomial certificates for no-instances as well.....

Answer (score 1):

We don't know for sure, but most people expect the answer is "no".  In particular, assuming NP != co-NP (as is a commonly held conjecture), the answer is "no".

Checking that a formula is satisfiable (and exhibiting a proof that it is) is a NP-complete problem.  Checking that a formula is unsatisfiable (and exhibiting a proof that it is not satisfiable) is a co-NP-complete problem.

Comment: unsatisfiability , imo, is fundamentally different than SAT. A formula is satisfiable by only a finite number of solutions, a single instance is enough to **prove** the formula is satisfiable, on the other hand, if a formula is unsatisfiable, we can never know just be checking for each solution cuz they will be infinite,  i don't think we can ever know if a formula is unsatisfiable  *polynomially*.......